# Pra que serve if __name__ == '__main__': se o kivy consegue executar o aplicativo sem essa linha de código?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy

Na documentação do kivy mostra que pro app funcionar é necessário

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Mas eu experimente remover a condição if; e o app executou mesmo assim; alguem me explica o porque, por favor!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu imaginei que tinha, mas não achei. A busca é meio chata quando é trecho de código. Acompanhei seu voto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É importante lembrar que além de poder executar um módulo diretamente, o Python tem a diretiva `import` para acrescentar outros módulos na mesma aplicação.

Ao iniciar um módulo, algumas variáveis são setadas automaticamente. A `__name__` é uma delas.

A condição

```
__name__ == "__main__"
```

só é verdadeira quando seu módulo é executado diretamente (*main* significa "principal").

Isto permite você ter um módulo que sirva tanto para importação, provendo seus métodos para a aplicação principal, mas que execute alguma coisa em especial quando chamado diretamente (ou que simplesmente tenha um comportamento diferenciado dentro do contexto em que é executado).

No seu caso específico, retirar a condição não fez diferença no teste por você ter testado apenas a chamada direta.

Para entender melhor, faça dois módulos, cada um com funções próprias, e um simples "print" no começo de ambos, e no primeiro dê um `import` no segundo. Execute o primeiro. Depois ponha o `if` em ambos como condição para o `print` e execute o primeiro novamente. Acrescentar um `print __name__` nos módulos também é interessante para ver a diferença.