# Crud com Python

Tags: python

Qual seria o problema desses códigos?

Alguém poderia me orientar qual a melhor pratica para fazer um sistema de cadastro, edição, exclusão e consulta?

**Primeiro código:**

```
class Cadastro:
  def __init__(self):
    self.nome = input('Digite nome do aluno: ')
    self.senha = input('Digite a senha: ')


  def aluno(self, nome, senha):
    self = Cadastro()
    self.nome = ' ' 
    self.senha = ' '
    return self
```

**Segundo código:**

```
class Cadastro:
  def __init__(self):
    self.nome = input('Digite nome do aluno: ')
    self.senha = input('Digite a senha: ')

  def aluno(self, nome, senha):
    self = Cadastro()
    self.nome = input('Digite nome do aluno: ')
    self.senha = input('Digite a senha: ')
    return self
```

**Terceiro código:**

**from lista import *
lista = []
while True:

```
opc = int(input('Cadastrar, digite 1\nConsultar, digite 2 \nOpção: '))
print()
if opc == 1:
    banco = (NovaConta())
    lista.append(banco)
    print('Cadastrado com sucesso! \nID: %i \nCliente: %s \nConta: %i '
          %(banco.ID, banco.cliente, banco.conta))
    print('-'*25)
elif opc == 2:

    consulta = int(input('Digite o ID: '))
    if consulta not in lista:
        print('Não contém')
    else:
        print(consulta[lista])**
```

**E salvei este arquivo com o seguinte nome lista.py:**

```
class usuario:
    ID = 0
    cliente = ' '
    conta = 0


def NovaConta():
    nc = usuario() 
    nc.ID = int(input('Digite um ID): '))
    nc.cliente = input('Digite Nome: ')
    nc.conta = int(input('Digite número da conta: '))
    print()
    return nc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor prática é isolar a sua lógica de interface da lógica de dados. A sua classe Alunos não tem que saber ou depender da interface, e a sua interface deve controlar o mínimo possível da lógica relacionada a um aluno.

Código modularizado (quer dizer, com componentes o mais independentes possível uns dos outros) trazem algumas vantagens:

- Melhor organização do código (cada sistema pode ficar em seu próprio arquivo/pasta/repositório, dependendo do tamanho do projeto)
- Melhor isolamento de bugs (um bug em um sistema isolado dificilmente tem causa em outro sistema, e portanto é mais fácil de encontrar)
- Você tem a liberdade de modificar ou até repor totalmente um sistema sem quebrar todo o programa

Sendo assim, pro seu exemplo de cadastro de alunos, usando só as estruturas básicas do Python, um bom programa seguiria moldes assim:

```
class Aluno:

    def __init__(self, nome, senha):  # Assim, você pode facilmente criar um aluno
        self.nome = nome
        self.senha = senha

    def mudar_senha(self, senha_antiga, senha_nova):
        if self.senha == senha_antiga:
            self.senha = senha_nova
            return True  # Sucesso
        else:
            return False  # Senha atual não confere

class Interface:

    alunos = []

    def cadastrar_aluno(self):
        nome = input('Quais é o nome do aluno?\n')
        senha = input('Quais é a senha desejada?\n')

        self.alunos.append(Aluno(nome, senha))
        print('Aluno adicionado!')

    def listar_alunos(self):
        for i, aluno in enumerate(self.alunos):
            print(i, aluno.nome)

    def mudar_senha(self):
        numero_aluno = input('Qual é o número de listagem do aluno?')
        numero_aluno = int(numero_aluno)

        senha_antiga = input('Quais é a senha atual?\n')
        senha_nova = input('Quais é a senha nova desejada?\n')
        sucesso = self.alunos[numero_aluno].mudar_senha(senha_antiga, senha_nova)

        if sucesso:
            print('Alteração realizada!')
        else:
            print('Erro ao tentar alterar senha!')


    def loop(self):
        while True:
            cmd = input('\n1 - Listar alunos\n2 - Cadastrar aluno\n3 - Mudar senha\n')
            if cmd == '1':
                self.listar_alunos()
            elif cmd == '2':
                self.cadastrar_aluno()
            elif cmd == '3':
                self.mudar_senha()
            else:
                print('Não entendi!')
                continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    interface = Interface()
    interface.loop()
```

Repare que a classe `Aluno` não sabe de nada sobre a interface, e a interface não cuida de nenhuma lógica própria da classe `Aluno`. Por exemplo, a função `mudar_senha` da interface pega os dados desejados, mas não toca diretamente na senha do aluno; essa lógica de mudança está dentro da classe `Aluno`.

Assim, você poderia facilmente trocar a interface de texto por uma gráfica e manter todo o seu código da classe `Aluno`.

Comment: Valeu! vou tentar compreender.

Comment: Pedro. Boa noite! Então, estou avaliando primeiro seu código e fiquei com dúvida.
def listar_alunos(self):
        for i, aluno in enumerate(self.alunos): 
            print(i, aluno.nome)
esse for concatenando o i e essa variável aluno qual o papel dela. Essa foi uma das dúvidas.
Grato!

Comment: A função listar alunos mostra na tela o número do aluno e depois o nome dele. O loop `for` itera sobre a lista `alunos` dada, e pra cada elemento na lista dá o nome `aluno` e executa o que tem dentro do seu bloco. O `enumerate` faz com que ao invés de só retornar cada elemento da lista, o `for` retorne também o número do elemento. Quer dizer, quando o for passa pelo primeiro aluno o valor de `i` é 0, no segundo é 1, e por aí vai. Assim, quando fazemos `print(i, aluno.nome)`, estamos printando o número de cada elemento da lista `alunos` e o nome do aluno correspondente.

Comment: Minha dúvida, era no for enumerate.
Valeu Pedro!

Comment: Bom dia Pedro! O que faz essa parte do código?
f __name__ == '__main__':
    interface = Interface()
    interface.loop()

Teria como, por gentileza, usar em outro simples exemplo? Nunca vi isso e estou vendo agora constantemente e não consegui compreender o que ele faz.
Grato.

Comment: Opa! Basicamente, serve pra rodar o código só se o arquivo principal for chamado. Isso serve pra evitar confusões em multiprocessing e pra ter comportamento diferente ao importar um arquivo como módulo ou executar ele diretamente. Aqui tem umas questões com respostas mais compreensivas: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280095/pra-que-serve-if-name-main-se-o-kivy-consegue-executar-o-aplicativ) [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92586/no-final-do-c%c3%b3digo-para-que-serve-a-express%c3%a3o-if-name-main)

Comment: Pelo que entendi, main é uma função que carrega um arquivo sem precisar invocar a função. Correto, mais ou menos isso?

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe de cadastro poderia ser assim:

```
import random

class Cadastro:
    def __init__(self):
    self.__nome = input('Digite nome do aluno: ')
    self.__senha = input('Digite a senha: ')
    self.__conta = self.__gerar_conta()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Cadastro(['nome': '{}', 'senha': '{}', 'conta': '{}'])".format(
        self.__nome, self.__senha, self.__conta
    )

    def __gerar_conta(self):
        return random.choice(range(3124, 9458))

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self.__nome

    @property
    def senha(self):
        return self.__senha

    @property
    def conta(self):
        return self.__conta

opcao = 0
contas = {}

while opcao != 3:
    opcao = int(input('\n\nCadastrar, digite 1\nConsultar, digite 2 \nPara sair, digite 3\nOpção: '))

    if opcao == 1:
        print('\n\nCadastrando novo usuário...')
        cadastro_novo = Cadastro()
        contas[cadastro_novo.conta] = cadastro_novo
        print(cadastro_novo)
    elif opcao == 2:
        conta = int(input('\n\nDigite o numero da conta: '))
        if conta in contas.keys():
            print(contas[conta])
        else:
            print('Conta #{} não existe.'.format(conta))
    elif opcao == 3:
        print('\n\nSaindo.')
    else:
        print('\n\nOpcao invalida.')
```

Comment: Obrigado! vou tentar compreender aqui.